# Applying css on <nav>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why isn't the CSS property applying to `<nav>`? Can we not do our own styling on these tags of bootstrap? If we can, how?

```css
nav{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          
<nav class="navbar bg-dark nav-light shadow">
  <h1 style="color:white">hello</h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: use `nav.navbar` to make it work... you can inspect element and see that *specificity* is at work here...

Comment: Also, make sure that your own CSS comes after the link to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @kukkuz CSS uses [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to apply styling. So simply editing the selector will do the trick

```css
nav.navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          
<nav class="navbar bg-dark nav-light shadow">
  <h1 style="color:white">hello</h1>
</nav>
```